# How to round numbers, remove "E"s from them and remove decimal points from whole numbers?

Tags: java, android

I have a crypto portfolio made, but the long percentage numbers or the "E"s instead of big numbers really tear up the design, like in this example:

[image]

How to fix them (round up to 2 decimal digits, remove E, remove .0 from 5)?

Comment: I see you're getting down voted.  That's because you haven't shown us that you have tried anything. Please click on edit and add your most recent attempt to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Math.round(number * 100.0) / 100.0;`

You can find plenty of other ways if you search.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Double constructor, you can turn all of those strings into doubles.

```
String someNumberString = "1.2E5";
Double dNum = new Double(someNumberString);
```

You can do rounding as such:

```
double rounded = (Math.round(dNum * ROUND_TO_OFFSET) / ROUND_TO_OFFSET)
```

where `ROUND_TO_OFFSET` specifies the digit to round to. E.g. `ROUND_TO_OFFSET= 100` rounds to the nearest 0.01. This has a disadvantage though. Math.round returns a long, so if your dNum * ROUND_TO_OFFSET produces a number that is larger or smaller than a long can hold, it will not work correctly.

You can format any double into a nice, easy to read format with the DecimalFormat class.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#####");
String formattedDouble = decimalFormat.format(someDouble);
```

This allows you to easily convert double values to strings that look like this: 
1,234,567.89012

If you need more precision or numbers larger than what Long.MAX_VALUE can handle, you should checkout java's BigDecimal class. 
BigDecimal provides it's own round method that allows you to specify what to round to. You can still use the DecimalFormat class by calling BigDecimal's `doubleValue()` function.